# Explain how Windows batch newline variable hack works

Tags: batch-file

Can someone please explain how this works?

```
@echo off
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
REM Example Usage:
echo There should be a newline%NL%inserted here.
```

emits:

```
There should be a newline
inserted here.
```

*from [How can you echo a newline in batch files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132799/how-can-you-echo-a-newline-in-batch-files/269819#269819)*

Comment: Is there a reason to do this other than to create a new blank line?

Comment: There are many, I added some explanations to my answer

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The trick uses the behaviour of the caret.
Also explained at [Long commands split over multiple lines in Windows Vista batch (.bat) file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69068/long-commands-split-over-multiple-lines-in-vista-dos-batch-bat-file/4455750#4455750)

The caret is an escape character for the next character, or at the line end it is used as multiline character, but this is nearly the same.

At the line end it simply escapes the next character, in this case the `<Linefeed>`, but there is a hidden feature, so if the escaped character is a `<LF>` it is ignored and the next character is read and escaped, but this charater will be always escaped, even if it is also a `<LF>`.

Now you can understand

```
set NLM=^


rem Two empty lines are required here
```

The NLM-Variable contains exactly one `<LF>` character.
But if you try to use it with `echo Line1%NLM%Line2` it fails, as the parser stops parsing at a single `<LF>`.
But this works

```
echo Line1^

Line2
```

So you need to add an escaped linefeed into the line and that is the NL-Variable.
The NL-Variable consists of only three characters.
`NL=^<LF><LF>`
And if this is expanded, it creates only one escaped `<LF>` as the first `<LF>` after the caret will be ignored.

Btw. In my opinion, it is much easier to use linefeeds with delayed expansion, as there is no need to escape anything.
In this example I use `%=EMPTY=%` instead of an empty line (for self commenting), but as the variable `=EMPTY=` can't exists it will be expanded to an empty line.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set NLM=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
echo Line1!NLM!Line2
```

**EDIT:** Append some hints for useful using the `<LF>`

1) Use it as newline in an `echo`

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
echo Line1!LF!Line2
```

2) Use it to split commands in a parenthesis block

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
(
    echo Line1%LF%set x=4%LF%echo !x!%LF%
)
```

3) Create a (nearly) empty EOL-chararcter in a FOR /F loop,
as `<LF>` is the line delimiter an EOL of `<LF>` is the same than an empty one.

```
FOR /F ^"eol^=^

delims^=^" %%a in (myFile.php) do echo %%a
```

4) Use LF for splitting text in a FOR /F loop

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%=EMPTY=%
)
set "var=Content1;Content2"
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ("%var:;=!LF!%") do (
  echo %%a
)
```

Comment: Great topic! How do I insert a newline character into a string that I will echo after I get the multi-line string built? Thanks

Comment: @RGuggisberg I'm not sure that I got your question, but perhaps you mean `set multiStr=Line1!LF!Line2 & echo !multiStr!`

Comment: Ahhh yes!  Got it. Thanks jeb

Comment: Just one more puzzle: you say the next character is <LF> but in fact it's the <CR> that is in front of the <LF>, isn't it?

Comment: @k314159 Yes, but carriage returns are removed by the parser in the previous phase

Answer (score 5):

There seems a [way](http://web.archive.org/web/20160101134129/http://www.misanthropicgeek.net/?p=469) that also works with pipe:

```
(echo 1st line^
&echo 2nd line) | sort
```

Comment: But this also sorts each line. So this trick does not work for concatenating multi-line files