# Batch how to recognize text files in the folder and store their filenames?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder called `newfolder` and there are abc.txt and def.txt inside of the folder. How can I store the file names `abc.txt` and `def.txt` into %file1% and %file2% using batch? The .cmd will be in the same directory as newfolder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to just assign the text `abc.txt` and `def.txt` to variables, use:

```
set file1=abc.txt
set file2=def.txt
```

But i assume from your question that you want to iterate through the file. If you explicitly wanted `abc.txt` to be in the variable `file1` and `def.txt` to be in `file2` use:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (*) do (
  if %%f==abc.txt set file1=abc.txt
  if %%f==def.txt set file2=file.txt
) else (
  rem process other files
)
```

If you just want to assign each text file in the folder to a variable, i would recommend setting a counter and using that to set the file variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set num=0
for /f %%f in ('dir /b /s') do (
  set /a num+=1
  set file!num!=%%f
)

rem now process it as you wish. example:

echo !file1!
echo !file2!
echo !file3!
echo !file4!
echo !file5!
echo !file6!

pause
```

Comment: In `('dir /b /s')` , what does dir ,/b , /s means ?If i want to include the target  
folder, is it put in this way `('dir /b /s newfolder')`?

Comment: `/s` includes sub directories and `/b` tells it to use bare format. And yes, you could add in a target folder. This code example was made to the specification that the batch file is in the same folder as the text files. If not, you could set the path like `('dir /b /s C:\Path\To\The\Folder\')`

Comment: You have given a lot of options, i have no reason not to choose you.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `set num=1
for /l %%x in(1,1,%%f) do (
 set /p first_six=<% file%num% % 
 echo first_six
        num+=1
pause
)` what i want to do is to echo file1 first line,echo file2 first line, echo file3 first line ... iteratively. But i just can not use `%` properly to make use of variable in another variable ,Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700256/bat-file-variable-contents-as-part-of-another-variable), it might answer your question. On another topic, if your following my 3rd example you need to use `!variable!` instead of `%variable%` when calling a variable (this is because i `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`

Answer (score 0):

```
set file1=abc.txt
set file2=def.txt
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to your answer will make it better.