# The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid

Tags: batch-file

in a.bat

```
if ... set a.b=1
...
set c=%%~!a.b!
```

echo %c% prints `%~1`, but I need contents of %~1.
but `set c=%~!a.b!` results in "The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter substitution is invalid: %~!a.b!." How to fix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the parameters with an evaluated expression directly,
as the percent expansion is one of the first [phases of the parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works/6379861#6379861).

But the *CALL-trick* can help you here.
Something like

```
set paramNo=1
call echo %%~%paramNo%
```

will expands first to
`call echo %%~1`
and the `CALL` will restart the parser, so you get your desired result.