# Newlines in batchfiles via caret ampersand echo. (^&echo.)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

So I learned today that a newline can be set via the following command:

```
 set nl=^&echo.
```

For example:

```
set nl=^&echo.
echo Hello%nl%world
```

yields

```
Hello
world
```

But why does this work? What is the significance of ^&?

Comment: Oh, I have seen this, it is "code injection".

Comment: See [Explain how dos-batch newline variable hack works](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6379619/1012053) for how to truly get a line feed character in a variable, with explanation and examples of how it can be used

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the code inside a .bat file, and do not set echo to off (leave echo on) and you will see how the commands are being expanded and executed.

#### Batch

```
set nl=^&echo.
echo One%nl%Two%nl%Three
```

#### Output

```
C:\>set nl=&echo.

C:\>echo One  & echo.Two & echo.Three
One
Two
Three
```

The `^` escapes the `&` special character so that it is a literal character able to be set inside the `nl` variable.  Then when the `nl` variable is expanded, the `&echo.` is inserted.

All is left is to deconstruct the `&echo.` part. The ampersand `&` means that a new command starts on the same line. That new command on the same line is `echo.`, which outputs a new line.

Comment: Thank you for your concise explanation!