# deleting content between lines containing certain words - in a text document

Tags: batch-file, text-files

i have a huge text file and i want to delete certain portions of it between two certain words.  e.g:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam
>   nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat
>   volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, **quis** nostrud exerci tation
>   ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
>   Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse
>   molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at
>   vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent
>   luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi.
>   Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil
>   imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non
>   habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum
>   claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius
>   quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui
>   sequitur mutationem consuetudium lectorum. Mirum est notare quam
>   littera **gothica.**

delete between "guis" and "gothica" words, it becomes:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, **quis  gothica**.

actually in the huge files there are lots of "gui" s and "gothica" s , i have to get rid of all of them.

this can be achieved with a simple batch script but i am so strange to the subject. TIA if anyone helps.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why a batch file? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried      type file.txt | findstr /v guis | findstr /v gothica           but it deletes only those lines including guis and gothica. i need to delete all lines between them. i hope you can help after this explanation.

Comment: Please do not confuse StackOverflow with a free code writing service! So show us what you have tried and describe precisely what you are encountering trouble with. Please read the entire [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn how this site works!

Comment: Ok, I see. The text you pasted shows up as all on one line, is that actually how the file looks? BTW, you may want to [edit] that into your question (that's probably why you got a downvote, people here like to see what you have tried on your own first). I'll try a couple things, but in the meantime this looks like it might be relevant? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33638832/batch-file-find-two-lines-then-copy-everything-between-those-lines

Comment: Your premise that this can be achieved via a simple batch file is false. It can be done (with some limitations, and slowly), but it is far from simple. In general, batch is not a good choice for manipulating text files. Simple solutions have many limitations. A robust solution requires a lot of arcane code.

Comment: @whrrgarbl  yes the topic is the just what i need, thanks. i tried the code trying to get the logic behind it, but it does not seem to work. and the answer has not been accepted by anyone. i am doubtful the script is correct.

Comment: @ dbenham  but i need a simple solution, not a robust solution for now.

Comment: @whrrgarbl  Perfect! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the simplest solution I came up with, which I'm sure has issues with things like special characters, but works with the given example. I used filenames `input.txt` and `output.txt`.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "FLAG=FALSE"
:: Define LF to contain a newline character
set LF=^


:: Do not remove above lines!
> output.txt (
    for /f "eol= tokens=*" %%A in (input.txt) do (
        set "ln=%%A"
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        for %%L in ("!LF!") do (
            for /f "eol= delims=., " %%W in ("!ln: =%%~L!") do (
                if "%%W"=="quis" (
                    set "FLAG=TRUE"
                    <nul set /p=%%W 
                ) else if "%%W"=="gothica" (
                    <nul set /p=%%W 
                    set "FLAG=FALSE"
                ) else if "!FLAG!"=="FALSE" (
                    <nul set /p=%%W 
                )
            )
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
```

This goes through each word and prints them out until it finds `quis`, and resumes printing out after it finds `gothica`. I used `<nul set /p=%%W` to echo without printing a newline (see 2nd and 3rd links), which has a side effect of printing out an extra space at the end of the file, so be aware of that.

References:

- [Read words separated by space in a batch script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112807/read-words-separated-by-space-in-a-batch-script)
- [Hidden features of Windows batch files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245395/hidden-features-of-windows-batch-files/374361#374361)
- [Windows batch: echo without new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7105433/windows-batch-echo-without-new-line)