# Evaluate an expression and send the result to another program in Windows Batch

Tags: bash, batch-file, expression-evaluation

I don't know how can i make this clear in a short sentence, so i give this example

Bash :

```
./foo $(ls -a)
```

First, "ls -a" is evaluated and converts to its output. So we 've got this line

```
./foo some_script Downloads
```

and then that's executed.

How can i achieve the same by using the windows command line?

P.S. : I need to use it when my IDE makes a build, so using PowerShell or CygWin is not an option

Comment: why don't you just pass a directory as an argument and then list files  of that directory inside ./foo script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the filenames contain no embedded spaces:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "args="
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /a /b') do set "args=!args!%%i "

.\foo %args%
```

Comment: I also needed the '\n' character, and found [some pretty ugly stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works)

But ended up doing everything in C#