# Replace string with a new line in Batch

Tags: batch-file, str-replace

```
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
SET memoli=%token:QMZ=%NL%%%
echo %memoli%>>%tmp%\list2.txt
```

I cant change the string "QMZ" with a new line. How to do that?

Comment: See this [nasty hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works) - or switch to a sane language - python, ruby, powershell..

Comment: SET memoli=%token:QMZ=%NL%%% 
This doesn't work.

Comment: You need the entire script including blank lines. Read and understand the linked question.

Comment: @RıdvanÇetin I tried as well and nothing works. I suggest [Blorgbeard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877969/replace-string-with-a-new-line-in-batch#comment38640710_24877969)'s suggestion that you switch to another language. `Ruby` and `Python` are open-source and their binaries can be easily installed. `Powershell` is also recommend over CMD scripting when in Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "token=HelloQMZworld"
echo !token:QMZ=^

!
```

It works as the batch parser parses first the multiline caret and replace it with a single linefeed.
Then in the delayed expansion phase it replaces the QMZ with a single linefeed, which is legal in that phase.

To set a new variable with the replaced string simply use

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "token=HelloQMZworld"
set newVal=!token:QMZ=^

!
echo !newVal!
```

Comment: Thank you for the better solution!

Comment: Except that this does not actually replace the characters in the variable, it only replaces them in the printed output.

Comment: @Synetech It works, but you didn't get a `!` into the variable by using `set "token=HelloQMZworld!"` you have to use `set "token=HelloQMZworld^!"` or set it before the delayed expansion will be enabled. I added a sample for moving the value into a variable

Answer (score 1):

```
set LF=^


rem ** Two empty lines required
FOR /F "delims=" %%a in ("%token:QMZ=!LF!%") do (
  echo %%a>>%tmp%\list2.txt
)
```

I was just wandering in the codes and I just did this unconsciously. But it does the trick.

Comment: +1 It works in many cases. But it will remove or modify strings containing exclamation marks, like `myTestToken!` or `my!path!`

Comment: But you did not replace anything in the variable. What if you don’t want to print it right away?

Comment: @jeb, yours doesn’t work with exclamation points either. `:-(`