# Batch script to extract part of a string

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch script that will read in another batch script (batch2) and:

- look for the string "configout:" OR "configin:"
- If it encounters one of these two strings, extract what's after it until the string ".xml"
- copy paste it in a new text file.
- and do this for each line of batch2.

For exemple:
If this is my first line in the batch script

```
/configin:%faxml%fm_sellin_in.xml /configout:%faxml%transco_fm_sellin_out%col_transco%.xml /inputfile:
```

I should have this in my text file:

```
%faxml%fa_sellin_in.xml
%faxml%transco_fm_sellin_out%col_transco%.xml
```

I have seen a good code in [Here](https://www.computing.net/answers/programming/batch-script-to-extract-parts-of-a-string/21596.html):

```
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=~" %%b in ("yourfile.txt") do (
  echo %%b >> newfile.txt
  echo removed %%a)
```

but i don't know how to adapt it to my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not replace all the `/configin` and `/configout` with newlines? -

([Replace string with a new line in Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877969/replace-string-with-a-new-line-in-batch))

For example

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "str=/configin:%%faxml%%fm_sellin_in.xml /configout:%%faxml%%transco_fm_sellin_out%%col_transco%%.xml /inputfile:"

set str=!str:/configin^:=^

!
set str=!str:/configout^:=^

!
```

Now, `!str!` would contain

```
fm_sellin_in.xml
transco_fm_sellin_out.xml /inputfile:
```

Then, you could use the `for` loop to extract the strings

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=. " %%a in ("!str!") do ()
```

this `for` loop iterates through each line and splits each line with the  and `.` characters.

So `%%a` is your file name and `%%b` is the extension.

then

```
if [%%b]==[xml] (echo %%a.%%b>>mytextfile.txt)
```

We will do this for all the lines of batch2.

And the finished code is

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims=" %%c in (batch2.txt) do (
set str=%%c
set str=!str:/configin^:=^

!
set str=!str:/configout^:=^

!
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=. " %%a in ("!str!") do (if [%%b]==[xml] (echo %%a.%%b>>mytextfile.txt))
)
```

Comment: It works very well thank you, that's what i was looking for. Can you explain to me what is the meaning of ^ and why did you use [xml] instead of (xml) ?

Comment: @R.Omar the `%%` and `^` are escape characters to tell the interpreter to treat it as a character instead of part of the `!var:find=replace!` or `%var%` syntax. I used `[xml]` instead of `(xml)` because [%%b] is a command line parameter.