# Batch modifying text.txt before a specific word

Tags: batch-file, text-manipulation

I have a file.txt where there are lines as

```
IF TANK T395 LEVEL ABOVE 4 THEN PUMP PFALDA395&T395 STATUS IS CLOSED
```

that I would like to transform in

```
IF TANK T395 LEVEL ABOVE 4
THEN PUMP PFALDA395&T395 STATUS IS CLOSED
```

I tried with this code.bat

```
@echo off
del "newfile.txt" 2>nul
(
    for /f "eol=| usebackq for /f tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,* delims= " %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g in ("oldfile.txt") do (
        for /f  %%h in ("%%g") do ( 
            if /i "%%h"=="THEN" ( 
                echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
                echo. %%g
            )
        )
        echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g
    )
)>"newfile.txt"
```

I got a fast

```
%b non atteso (not waited)
```

What am I stumbling in?

Comment: You can only use one `for`-variable: `for /f "<options>" %%a in ("oldfile.txt") do ( `. `%%b`, `%%c`,... are implicit (working anyways; `tokens=x` implies them). (Described in `for /?`)

Comment: So the keyword `THEN` is the only condition for splitting the line of text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tried to specify variables for all tokens in the outer `for` command, but you must specify only the first one, which is `%%a` in your case; all the others (`%%b`, `%%c`,..., `%%g`) are defined implicitly via the `tokens` option (see also @Stephan's comment).

Besides that, your code outputs the original *and* the split line into the output file. Hence I inserted an `else` clause.

Finally, I implemented an additional condition: the code searches for `IF` as well now and splits therefore only lines which start with `IF` and contain `THEN` as the 7th token.

```
@echo off
del "newfile.txt" 2> nul
(
    for /f "eol=| usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,* delims= " %%a in ("oldfile.txt") do (
        if /i "%%a"=="IF" (
            for /f "eol=| tokens=1 delims= " %%h in ("%%g") do ( 
                if /i "%%h"=="THEN" ( 
                    echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
                    echo %%g
                ) else (
                    echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g
                )
            )
        ) else (
            echo %%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g
        )
    )
) > "newfile.txt"
```

---

**Edit:**
The above solution can be simplified after following @Aacini's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32173146/batch-modifying-text-txt-before-a-specific-word/32175639#comment52252353_32175639):

```
@echo off
del "newfile.txt" 2> nul
(
    for /f "eol=| usebackq tokens=1-7* delims= " %%a in ("oldfile.txt") do (
        if /i "%%a|%%g"=="IF|THEN" (
            echo.%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f
            echo.%%g %%h
        ) else (
            echo.%%a %%b %%c %%d %%e %%f %%g %%h
        )
    )
) > "newfile.txt"
```

Herein, only one `for` loop and one `if` clause is required.

Comment: You repeated `for /f`, please review it so your text will perform as expected

Comment: This trick makes a simpler solution: `for /f "eol=| tokens=1-7*" %%a in ("oldfile.txt") do if /i "%%a-%%g" equ "IF-THEN" then (echo %%a .. %%f & echo %%g %%h) else echo %%a .. %%h`

Comment: @Aacini, thanks for the advice! I just copied the original code and inserted the `if`s/`else`s and did not think aboud improving the rest of the code, but I'll edit my answer accordingly...

Answer (score 2):

just replace every `<space>THEN<space>` with `<newline>THEN<space>`:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%

for /f "delims=" %%a in (t.txt) do (
  set line=%%a
  echo(!line: THEN =%NL%THEN !
)
```

(I took the creation of a NewLine from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6379619/2152082))

Comment: I like this one! **`:)`**