# How to split words vertically when space is encountered?

Tags: batch-file

I have a `Sample.txt` file where the content is:

> ```
> Hi How Are You?
> ```

Using batch file, I have to split the words vertically after every space. Output should be like this:

> ```
> Hi
> How
> Are
> You?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (sample.txt) do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do (
    echo %%b
  )
)
```

First (outer) `for` processes each line in the file, second (inner) `for` processes each word in that line.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file into a variable, using:

```cmd
< "Sample.txt" set /P LINE=""
```

Or, if the line is longer than 1021 bytes (!), using this:

```cmd
for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("Sample.txt") do (
    set "LINE=%%L"
)
```

Then you could replace every <kbd>SPACE</kbd> by a line-break, like this:

```cmd
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!LINE: =^

!
endlocal
```

Or, when first storing the line-break in a variable, like this:

```cmd
(set LF=^

)
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo(!LINE: =^%LF%%LF%!
endlocal
```

The empty line in each of the above code variants is mandatory to get a line-break in the output. Reference [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379861) by user [jeb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/463115) for how this new-line hack works.

I am using [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) here in order to avoid trouble with special characters.