# Multiple lines for one String batch

Tags: string, batch-file, cmd

I Googled it but i'm not able to find a GOOD solution.

My goal is to put a string which is composed of 6 lines in one string, and only one, in a variable.

For example, my string can look like :

```
a
b
c
```

and I want it to be in one string. I tried the thing witch `^`, or with `ECHO " "` but it doesn't work : the cmd put an error "not recognized as an internal command" (and it's normal, it's just some sentences, not batch commands!)

Thanks, Clément

Answer (score 0):

Not so simple but [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works) :

```
@echo off
REM Creating a Newline variable (the two blank lines are required!)
set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
REM Example Usage:
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "string_with_new_lines=a!nl!b!nl!c"
echo %string_with_new_lines%
```

[Aacini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/778560/aacini) has a simpler solution for this using empty variable,but I'm struggle to find the link.

Comment: It looks like it works for "a b c" but i'm using it for SQL (exactly SPARQL) commands and it's not working.
Indeed : `set "string_with_new_lines=PREFIX resources: <http://www.fluidops.com/resource/>!nl!"

echo %string_with_new_lines%` doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Comment: @ClementB - what is the error message? Are you using `<` and `>` in your code? If yes they should be escaped with caret: `^<` and `^>` . Better paste the whole code you want to execute ,because it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hey. It doesn't counter the `<` symbol. In reality, it does but after that, the !nl! is ignored.

Comment: @ClementB - please paste more code in your question. If you want to pass multiline parameter probably it wont be possible. Probably your tool can accept SQL script file as argument?

Comment: By the way, your idea of a file is genius. I'll try this immedialty.

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments on the post answer of @npocmaka

It's currently in Python, so the `"""` thing works.

```
requete = """
            PREFIX resources: <http://www.fluidops.com/resource/> 
            SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?marque ?modele WHERE { 
              ?voiture resources:uid ?id.
              ?voiture resources:bpqmqvc ?marque. #myComment
              ?voiture resources:bpqmodvc ?modele 
            } 
        """
```