# Toggling execuation of dispersed lines in batch-file (Example: debug/trace lines)

Tags: batch-file, debugging, cmd

**Question**

Is it possible to have a single-check toggle for the execution of multiple non-sequential lines in a batch file?

**My Usage**

Debug/trace lines that are distributed throughout the code.

**Other Usages**

I suppose this could be used in other ways, like enabling certain logic, but usually that would be better handled by flow of control.

---

I'm posting my own answer here that seems to work well. Feel free to share if you have other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have toggleable lines of code, you can do something like this, example being a debug/trace implementation.

```
@Echo Off

::Set trace bit
set trace=0
::Optional: Prompt to enable
set /p trace=Trace is disabled. Enter 1 to enable: 

::Implement trace bit
if %trace% EQU 1 (
set trace=
) else (
set trace=@REM
) 

::Example Script (Lines that begin with %trace% are dependent on trace bit)
%trace% @Echo On
set x=5
%trace% @Echo Trace1: x=%x%
set /a y=5*%x%
%trace% @Echo Trace2: y=%y%
Echo On
set /a y=5*%y%
%trace% @Echo Trace3: y=%y%

pause
```

**Explanation**

This technique works by setting a parameter (%trace% in this example) to be a non-printing comment `@REM` if trace is off (= 0). This in effect masks your entire line of code by making it appear as a comment. If trace is enabled (= 1), then the %trace% variable is empty and the entire line of code executes as normal.

**Line Masking Choice**

The %Trace% variable could simply be `REM`, which will behave like `@REM` so long as you have `Echo Off`; however, if you have `Echo On`, it results in printed REM lines for the no trace option (trace = 0). For this reason, `@REM` is probably preferred.

[image]

Versus this...

[image]

Alternatives to `@REM` are `<linefeed>` or `::` to mask the entire line and produce the following output even with `Echo On` and trace = 0; however, both of these options are problematic inside of bracketed code segments. The only benefit I can think of for them is that they might be faster, but that should be negligent.

`<linefeed>` is a non-obvious choice and works because the parser stops parsing and goes to the next line whenever it encounters a linefeed character. To set a variable equal to linefeed is a little tricky, but can be done as follows...

```
if %trace% EQU 1 (
set trace=
) else (
set trace=


) 
::The two new lines after "trace=" are required
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works) as to why two lines are needed.

Comment: As you said `::` is problematic in parenthesis blocks, but `<linefeed>` fails completely in blocks, as it works like a command separator. `REM` is seems to be the best solution and even in `ECHO ON` mode it can safely used with `set "trace=@REM "`

Comment: @jeb  I thought about the `<LineFeed>` breaking in parentheses blocks too, but didn't test it; thanks for testing. Excellent point, `@REM` is probably the best overall solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it's more obvious and more readable to use `REM` instead of the "linefeed trick"

```
@echo off
choice /c YN /m "enable debugging?"
if errorlevel 2 (set "debug=REM") else (set "debug=@")
::Example Script (Lines that begin with %debug% are dependent on debug bit)
%debug% @Echo On
set x=5
%debug% Echo debug1: x=%x%
set /a y=5*%x%
%debug% Echo debug2: y=%y%
set /a y=5*%y%
%debug% Echo debug3: y=%y%
echo last result: %y%
pause
```

Comment: Ha, that's so obvious I feel silly for having posted with the linefeed method. I wonder if there's any functional difference?

Comment: Aw, there is a difference. If you have an `Echo On` section then the REM lines will still print.

Comment: might even be an advantage... `set "debug=@REM"` to suppress.

Comment: yep, that's what jeb suggested too, `@REM` seems like the best solution.