# Get Output of an ADB command into a variable in Batch/CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd, adb

so I have this piece of code;

```
adb shell for i in $(seq 0 10); do h=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone$i/type`; t=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone$i/temp`; echo "$h : $t C"; done;
```

which outputs the connected adb device's thermals. this code alone does the job, but i want each of them aligned nicely, which in this code it outputs the name of the thermal and the temps in a way that its hard to read because the are not aligned

normally how i would deal with these is to output the name of thermal and the temp into 2 variables `%thermalname%` and `%temp%` and then later `echo` both of them as shown.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%f IN (`adb shell for i in $(seq 0 10); do h=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone$i/type`;`) DO set thermalname=%%f

FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%f IN (`adb shell for i in $(seq 0 10); do t=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone$i/temp`;`) DO set temp=%%f

echo %thermalname% %temp%
```

**but the above code would NOT work, as the adb command itself contains backquotes :( i tried replacing backquote with a single quote, but then the adb command doesnt work. (also tried the same for the `for` command but it gives an error and wont work)**

in such a situation, how can i get the output into a variable, or is there an even easier way?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you considered appending a newline to your `echo`? For example, like it's done in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6379861/6133426

Comment: actually the problem is that i cant get a variable to `echo` in the first place. please read my post again, i think you misunderstood. thanks.

Comment: Apologies, but from this -  `adb shell for i ...` I understood that you do get an output, which is not "aligned nicely". No mention of variables there, or in my original comment. What I meant was - can you append a newline character to this: `echo "$h : $t C"` ? **EDIT** By "not aligned nicely" - do you mean that everything is in one line of text, and difficult to analyze?

Comment: Change the first __FOR /F__ command line to ``FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('adb shell for i in $(seq 0 10^)^; do h^=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone$i/type`^;') DO set "thermalname=%%G"`` and the second to ``FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('adb shell for i in $(seq 0 10^)^; do t^=`cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone$i/temp`^;') DO set "temp=%%G"``. There cannot be used back quotes for the entire command line if it contains itself back quotes. The characters `);=` must be additionally escaped with `^` to be interpreted as literal characters by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file.

Comment: thank you @Mofi it really helped. thanks for the additional info of 'escaping characters' so they work properly.