# Extract string that contains delimiter of full string

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I have a little batch script that gets the temporary password from `mysql.err` file.

But I have a problem when a password contains `:` that is used in delimiter match resulting password will not get as is..

Is there any other approach to get correctly the password?

```
@echo off

setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

set mysql_dir=C:\database\mysql

echo.
echo.
echo Search For Current MySQL Password
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=:" %%G in ('find /I "A temporary password is generated for root@localhost:" ^<%mysql_dir%\data\%ComputerName%.err') DO set temp_mysql_password="%%G"

echo.
echo.
echo Current MySQL password: %temp_mysql_password%
```

The `mysql.err` file content is:

```
2017-08-31T07:38:36.195916Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
2017-08-31T07:38:36.205943Z 22 [Note] A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: v>dqu;;&)7:Y
2017-08-31T07:38:42.510215Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
```

And the problem is with that the password
`v>dqu;;&)7:Y`** that contains `:` will be extracted as:
`v>dqu;;&)7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way without delimiters it will work:

```
...
for /F "delims=" %%G in ('find /I "A temporary password is generated for" ^<%mysql_dir%\data\%ComputerName%.err') do (
   set "temp_mysql_password=%%G"
   set "temp_mysql_password=!temp_mysql_password:*A temporary password is generated for root@localhost: =!"
)


echo.
echo.
rem Note the ! around the variable
echo Current MySQL password: !temp_mysql_password!
```

It uses string manipulation which is explained [here: Remove - Remove a substring using string substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.Remove).

Note that it will just work for `root@localhost` because that string is part of the string searched for substitution.

To make it work for any `user@host` combination you have to use 3 string substitutions instead of one:

```
set "temp_mysql_password=!temp_mysql_password:*A temporary password is generated for =!"
set "temp_mysql_password=!temp_mysql_password:*@=!"
set "temp_mysql_password=!temp_mysql_password:*: =!"
```

**Output:**

```
Current MySQL password: v>dqu;;&)7:Y
```

---

To use your solution anyway (using `tokens` and `delims`) you could concate all the delimited parts, see [here on SO how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631935/8051589).

Comment: Thank you for your time! Is it work as expected. Nice aproach!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd used "tokens=3* delims=:" and the next for variable %%H you'd get the unparsed password.
The asterisk representing the remainder of the input without further splitting at delims.

```
@echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set mysql_dir=C:\database\mysql
echo.
echo.
echo Search For Current MySQL Password
FOR /F "tokens=3* delims=:" %%G in (
    'find /I "A temporary password is generated for root@localhost:" ^<%mysql_dir%\data\%ComputerName%.err'
) DO set "temp_mysql_password=%%H"
set "temp_mysql_password=%temp_mysql_password:~1%"
echo.
echo.
echo Current MySQL password: %temp_mysql_password%
```

Comment: The password will be: `" v>dqu;;&)7:Y"` (with quotes). Test it with: `echo Current MySQL password: ^<%temp_mysql_password%^>`. But even if the set command (causing the quotes) is right: `set "temp_mysql_password=%%H"` it will be with a beginning whitespace. Okay this can easily be removed, so it's a nevertheless a good answer after the corrections. Note that it just works for: `root@localhost`.

Comment: @AndreKampling Agreed, I wasn't thorough enaugh revising the code. Changed.

Comment: works with every user, when changing the search string to just `"A temporary password is generated for "`