# Extract a given ancestor path form a deeper path in Windows CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have no idea how to get what described here using an Win CMD batch script:

**pseudo-code**

```
set aPath=C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system
set aDir=file
... some logic here 
echo %result%
```

Should print

```
C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file
```

It should stop at the first occurrence found, but it would be nice to specify also the occurence (optional).

**ONLY Windows CMD SOLUTIONS ARE WELCOME** no Powershell code nor external tools, please. I'm looking for a pure Windows CMD solution.

Comment: With `setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion` in batch file above the line `for /F "delims=|" %%I in ("!apath:\%aDir%\=\%aDir%|!") do endlocal & set "result=%%I"`, the output is as wanted by you. This works only if `aDir` does not contain `=`. If `aDir` is not found case insensitive in `aPath`, `result` is equal `aPath` like on `aDir` being last directory in `aPath` if `aPath` does not end with a backslash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure to what you refer with occurence

Using a shuffle approach and self modifying code to get the dir levels

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\08\29\SO_57717256.cmd
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "aPath=C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system"
set "aDir=file"
echo aPath = %aPath%
echo aDir  = %aDir%

::... some logic here 
set "intermediate=!apath:*%aDir%=!"
set "result=!aPath:%intermediate%=!"

:: and some vodoo there ;-)
Set i=0
Set "aPath=%aPath:\="&Set /a i+=1&Set "aPath[!i!]=%"

echo result= %result%

for /l %%L in (1,1,%i%) Do if "%aDir%"=="!aPath[%%L]!" (
    echo aPath[%%L] = !aPath[%%L]! ^<^<^< matches aDir %aDir%
) else (
    echo aPath[%%L] = !aPath[%%L]!
)
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\08\29\SO_57717256.cmd
aPath = C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system
aDir  = file
result= C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file
aPath[1] = just
aPath[2] = a
aPath[3] = long
aPath[4] = path
aPath[5] = to
aPath[6] = a
aPath[7] = file <<< matches aDir file
aPath[8] = in
aPath[9] = the
aPath[10] = file <<< matches aDir file
aPath[11] = system
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little approach using a recursive sub-routine, just for fun:

```cmd
@echo off
set "aPath=C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system"
set "aDir=file"
set "result=" & set "found="

call :RECURSIVE "%aPath%\."
if defined found echo/%result%
exit /B

:RECURSIVE
    if "%~nx1" == "" set "result=%~dp1" & exit /B
    call :RECURSIVE "%~dp1."
    if defined found (exit /B) else set "result=%result%%~nx1\"
    if /I "%~nx1" == "%aDir%" set "found=#" & set "result=%result:~,-1%"
```

This makes use of the [`~` modifiers](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of command line or sub-routine arguments (parameters), which allow to split a path into pieces.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set aPath=C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system\filenot\file\folder
set aDir=file
echo    %aPath%

rem This FOR is just for testing; remove it...
for /L %%n in (1,1,3) do (
   set "n=%%n"
   set "result="
   for %%a in ("!aPath:\%aDir%\=" "!") do if !n! gtr 0 set "result=!result!%%~a\%aDir%\" & set /A n-=1
   echo %%n: !result:~0,-1!
)
```

Output example:

```
   C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system\filenot\file\folder
1: C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file
2: C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file
3: C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system\filenot\file
```

**EDIT**: An even simpler method with the aid of [some magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524928/dos-batch-iterate-through-a-delimited-string/33091367#33091367):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set aPath=C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system\filenot\file\folder
set aDir=file
echo    %aPath%

set n=%1
set "result="
set "p=%aPath:\=" & (if !n! gtr 0 set "result=!result!\!p!") & (if "!p!" equ "!aDir!" set /A n-=1) & set "p=%"
echo %1: %result:~1%
```

Output example:

```
C:\Tests> test 1
   C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system\filenot\file\folder
1: C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file

C:\Tests> test 2
   C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file\system\filenot\file\folder
2: C:\just\a\long\path\to\a\file\in\the\file
```